# AWS Close Ports on Specific Elastic IP Addresses for EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-ip

I have a Windows Server in AWS EC2. I have opened ports 80 and 443 to 0.0.0.0/0, and RDP to a private IP address for VPN access. The instance has 4 total elastic IP addresses, each mapping to a private IP address on the instance via an EC2 Network Interface. I want to close port 80 to all traffic on one of the IP addresses, but leave it open to the other three. Is this possible in AWS/VPC?

Here's the current table...

```
Private    | Public  | Ports Open
------------------------------------
10.0.0.220 | x.x.x.1 | 80, 443, 3389
10.0.0.221 | x.x.x.2 | 80, 443, 3389
10.0.0.223 | x.x.x.3 | 80, 443, 3389
10.0.0.224 | x.x.x.4 | 80, 443, 3389
```

Here's the goal...

```
Private    | Public  | Ports Open
------------------------------------
10.0.0.220 | x.x.x.1 | 80, 443, 3389
10.0.0.221 | x.x.x.2 | 80, 443
10.0.0.223 | x.x.x.3 | 80, 443
10.0.0.224 | x.x.x.4 | 443
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried a security group?  You can assign a security group to a specific interface if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as suggested by @NetRay was to create additional Security Groups, each with the ports rules needed, and then create new Network Interfaces and apply those to Security Groups to the interfaces as needed.